# MPOAuth iOS MPOAuthMobile does not handle return to callback

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

I have troubles with MPOAuth on iOS. I'm trying to authorize application on Twitter, and everything is going ok till the point when twitter returns user back to the application via callback url.

If you look at the OAuth flow chart on twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#oauth you'll see that on step D service (twitter) returns user to consumer (my iOS application) and it provides oauth_token and oauth_verifier to consumer via parameters in callback. Then my iOS application handles this request and everything stops. In MPOAuthMobile application shipped with MPOAuth library code that parses request in application delegate's `application:handleOpenURL:` is as this:

```
NSDictionary *oauthParameters = [MPURLRequestParameter parameterDictionaryFromString:[url query]];
self.oauthVerifier = [oauthParameters objectForKey:@"oauth_verifier"];
```

It doesn't do anything with this request, but it should as twitter for `access_token`.
Can you please tell me how to handle this request and how to tell MPOAuth library that it is time to request `access_token`?